# automated facebook login failing through python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying this just for fun.
I am able to insert username and password
but unable to click the login button
can you tell what is the problem with the following code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


def init_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    return driver


def login(driver,page,inputUsername,inputPassword):
    driver.get(page)
    try:
        email1 = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.ID,"email")))
        email1.send_keys(inputUsername)
        password1 = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.ID,"pass")))
        password1.send_keys(inputPassword)
        button1 = driver.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.ID,"u_0_n")))
        button1.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Box or Button not found in google.com")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    page = "https://facebook.com"
    username = ""
    password = ""
    driver = init_driver()
    login(driver, page,username,password)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: your code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
button1.click()
```

to

```
button1.submit()
```

like in this example http://www.thetaranights.com/login-to-a-website-using-selenium-python-python-selenium-example/.

Answer (score 0):

problem is in this part

```
button1 = driver.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.ID,"u_0_n")))
```

button id are sometimes different when web pages are opened by selenium so the
correct id for login button should be

```
u_0_1
```

not

```
u_0_n
```